# How to generate dynamic input parameters in terraform modules?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm new to terraform, so this might sound like a silly question, so please bear with me.

I have 2 resources pubsub-to-firestore and pubsub-to-bigquery

```html
resource "google_dataflow_job" "pubsub-to-firestore-dataflow" {
  name              = "${var.dataflow_name}"
  template_gcs_path = var.template_gcs_path
  temp_gcs_location = "gs://${google_storage_bucket.dataflow-bucket.name}/${google_storage_bucket_object.dataflow-bucket-object-path.name}"
  parameters = {
    pubSubSubscription  = google_pubsub_subscription.dataflow_subscription.id
    firestoreCollection = var.firestore_collection
    keys                = var.firestore_collection_keys
  }
  service_account_email = data.google_service_account.dataflow_account.email
  region                = var.job_region
  on_delete             = "cancel"
}
```

and

```html
resource "google_dataflow_job" "pubsub-to-firestore-dataflow" {
  name              = "${var.dataflow_name}"
  template_gcs_path = var.template_gcs_path
  temp_gcs_location = "gs://${google_storage_bucket.dataflow-bucket.name}/${google_storage_bucket_object.dataflow-bucket-object-path.name}"
  parameters = {
    inputSubscription = google_pubsub_subscription.dataflow_subscription.id
    outputTableSpec   = "${var.google_project_name}:${var.bigquery_dataset}.${var.bigquery_table}"
    outputDeadletterTable = (
      var.bigquery_table_error_records != ""
      ? "${var.google_project_name}:${var.bigquery_dataset}.${var.bigquery_table_error_records}"
      : null
    )
  }
  service_account_email = data.google_service_account.dataflow_account.email
  region                = var.job_region
  on_delete             = "cancel"
}
```

As you can see, all the input variables are same, except for the "parameters" var.
I want to combine these two into a generic "pubsub-to-db" resource, where I want to dynamically generate the "parameters" object. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how to manage resources with dynamic argument values. You would want https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html. Where this would get tricky is because of the conditionals in your `parameters` Map value, where you would also need https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html. Give it a try and update/ask if something does not work out for you.

Comment: How do you differentiate between the two resources?